# Replace Mesh into Spot Light

Tags: mesh, light

can I turn meshes into light object?
Like 10 cones into 10 spot lights

I use SketchUp as my main modelling software & cycles as my main renderer.

The idea are... I place a cone (mesh) on every downlights on sketchup, then later, I want to replace all of them with spot light (light) on blender. is there any way how to do that?

thanks.

Comment: Uhh... this is VERY unconventional. However, if the cones actually DO ex/import as individual objects and not one big object or 500 individual face objects, this can be done rather easily.

Comment: The cones actually do import as individual objects on blender. 10 mesh on sketchup = 10 mesh on blender. Why can't I comment on people answer, on my own threads? :(

Comment: Can reply to comments from your original [Raha](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/121367/raha) account.  _This is another with same username_. [Edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/218445/edit) any extra details into question.